# Triple-T Publisher upgrade version fails to upload to GPC

Tags: android, gradle, google-play, cicd

I'm using the `Triple-T gradle-play-publisher` to upload a release to the Play store.
Current version is
`id("com.github.triplet.play") version "2.6.2"`
and using `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'`
It works fine and generates and pushes to the store with `publishReleaseApk`.
But when I moved to `3.7.0` I got the following issue:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:publishReleaseApk'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.github.triplet.gradle.play.tasks.PublishApk$Processor
   > There was a failure while executing work items
      > A failure occurred while executing com.github.triplet.gradle.play.tasks.PublishApk$ApkUploader
         > 'boolean com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport.isMtls()'
```

What should I change also?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because of using `Triple-T` and `Firebase App Distribution`, I managed to resolve it by upgrading both libraries to the latest versions.
After that, I found `fastlane` that provides the same functionality as `Triple-T` so I migrated my gradle code to `fastlane`.